# how to set private endpoint in zuul

Tags: spring, spring-security, netflix-zuul

how to set private endpoint in zuul?

env: spring, zuul

i'm using

```
zuul:
  routes:
    abc:
      path: /abc/**
      sensitive-headers:
      url: http://abc.api.develop.com
```

in abc service, i want to make private `/abc/xyz/1/test`.

only it has to be work, when i request directly to `http://abc.api.develop.com/xyz/1/test` in server. not `https://develop.com/abc/xyz/1/test` by gateway.

`/abc/1`, `/abc/1/public`, `/abc/xyz/2/good` etc have to be public.
so only one path(`/abc/xyz/1/test`) is private endpoint.

how to set this?
can anyone help me please?
or any hint?

is zuul setting or is spring security setting?

how to block this specific path?

Answer (score 0):

I used `ignoredPatterns: /abc/xyz/*/good`.